# Direct ajax() or post() request of an URL

Tags: ajax, jquery-post

I have an url with query args:

```
var url = 'http://example.com/ajax.php?action=update_count&product=1234'
```

So, all query args I need to send for ajax request is already in URL, I tried this:

```
$.post( url, '', callback, 'json');
```

But, it won't send POST data.

So, I want to ask shall I do ajax/post request without data object/string, as query args are already in url.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use `load()` jQuery function? Works well when using get requests.

Comment: Yes I seen the documents for `load()` but I am not so sure about, can I get data as `json`, success `callback` etc

Comment: Well, you are using post function to send get requests, you need to use `get()` or `load()`, or even `ajax()`.

Comment: OK, I will try once with ajax(). thanks

Comment: jQuery has the function `getJSON()` too. You can use to get requests, see: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/. Is simple to use.

Answer (score 2):

If you put a parameter in the URL, it's treated like a `GET` parameter, not a `POST` parameter. You need to use whatever server-side mechanism is normally used for getting URL parameters. For instance, in PHP it would be `$_GET['action'] and`$_GET['product']`.

If you want to be able to send a parameter in either `GET` or `POST`, you can use PHP's `$_REQUEST` variable. It merges both sets of parameters.